# Help Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve this differential equation $$(2x+y)dx + (x-2y)dy=0$$ as an exact differential equation and I know it's exact because I solve the equaliy  $$ \frac{\partial(2x+y)}{\partial y} = 1$$ and $$\frac{\partial(x-2y)}{\partial x} = 1$$ so following the steps to solve this kind of equations i have:
$$ x^2+g'(y) = x-2y $$ and $$g'(y) = \frac {x-2y}{x^2}$$ to be honest I have many doubts what are the next steps so if you can guide me I'll apreciate

Comment: Note that $\frac{\partial(x-2xy)}{\partial x}=1-2y.$ Is it correct your initial equation?

Comment: @mfl sorry I just fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is $F(x,y) = C$ such that
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = 2x + y$$
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = x - 2y$$

Treating $y$ as constant, integrate the first equation with respect to $x$
$$F(x,y) = \int (2x + y) \, dx = x^2 + xy + g(y) $$

Treating $x$ as constant, take the partial w.r.t. $y$ of the above expression
$$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = x + g'(y) = x - 2y $$

This gives 
$$ g'(y) = -2y \Rightarrow g(y) =-y^2$$
$$ F(x,y) = x^2 + xy - y^2 $$

so the solution is
$$ x^2 + xy - y^2 = C $$

Comment: So hard, even if this, is one of the easiest equations, anyway thank you, I just want to cry cause this is a nightmare

Comment: You'll get used to it. Good luck!